# How to exclude one collection element from serialization in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `Set` of `Components`:

```
final class User{

    private final Set<Component> COMPONENTS;

    public User(String userID)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        COMPONENTS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                     new AuthorizationComponent(this.getUserID())
                     new ProfileComponent(this.getUserID()),
                     new ThemeComponent(this.getUserID()))
            ));
    }
}
```

Each component: Auth, Profile, Theme is a subclass of a `Component`.

Now, I create a `User` and convert it to a `JSON` string:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

I need to exclude the `AuthorizationComponent` from this `String`. I know I can use a `transient` modifier and a `@JsonIgnore` annotation - but this works only on fields and I need to remove only one collection element.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this link helpful for you? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this is possible, at least not without a significant effort. You could write your own custom serializer (see [Jackson How-To: Custom Serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers)). For example, you could customize the serializer for  `Set` and filter out the "bad" classe. However, I am not sure this is worth the effort, particular with respect to maintaining the code later, since understanding the solution will require a lot of familiarity with Jackson's internals.

Other options:

- Instead of having a single field with a `Set`, use separate fields. Either separate fields inside class `User`, or create a container object (`ConfigComponents` or similar), which then has a field per component. In my experience, using plain `Set` or `List` to contain instances of different classes is usually not a good solution - you want something with more structure.
- Instead of excluding `AuthorizationComponent` completely, only exclude the fields of the class that cause a problem. That side-steps the issue.

What is most appropriate in your case will depend on your project, and how the classes are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can define **a custom Serializer** for the class `User`.

Source : [Jackson – Custom Serializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

Example of custom Serializer :

```
public class ItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {

    public ItemSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ItemSerializer(Class<Item> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
      Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
        jgen.writeStringField("itemName", value.itemName);
        jgen.writeNumberField("owner", value.owner.id);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```